# How to check if an object is in another queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I need to check if a user has liked a post on a page that displays all posts, I am passing the posts and user's likes below

```
def index(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    text = request.POST["post-text"]
    Post.objects.create(
        entity = Entity.objects.create(
            user = request.user,
            text = text
        )
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

return render(request, "network/index.html", {
    "posts" : Post.objects.all().order_by('-entity__date', '-entity__id'),
    "likes" : Like.objects.filter(user = request.user)
})
```

this is the model

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="posts")
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

class Like(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="likes")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="likes")

class Post(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post")
```

Template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div>
  <div>{{post.entity.user}}</div>
  <div>{{post.entity.text}}</div>
  <div>{{post.entity.date}}</div>
  <div class="like-btn d-inline" data-id="{{post.entity.id}}">
    {% if post.entity in likes %}
    <p>yes</p>
    {%else%}
    <p>no</p>
    {%endif%}

    <div class="d-inline">{{post.entity.likes.count}}</div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <a href="#">Comment</a>
  <hr />
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know how to write the if condition, I've tried this {% if post.entity in likes %} but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't*. While this can be done with such condition, it would result in a *lot* of extra queries. You can work with a [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST['post-text']
        Post.objects.create(
            entity = Entity.objects.create(
                user = request.user,
                text = text
            )
        )
        return redirect('index')
    posts = Post.objects.annotate(
        is_liked=Exists(
            Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, entity_id=OuterRef('entity_id')
        )
    ).select_related('entity').order_by('-entity__date', '-entity__id')
    
    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        'posts' : posts
    })
```

The `Post` objects will then have an extra attribute `.is_liked` that is `True` if that `Post` is liked by the logged in user.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: You can make use of [**`redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) instead
> of first calling [**`reverse(…)`** <sup>[Django]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) and
> then wrap it in a [**`HttpResponseRedirect`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect).
> The `redirect(…)` function does not only offer a more convenient signature to do this, it also for example will use the
> [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url)
> if you pass it a model object.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to perform the logic of sorting the Entities/Likes/User inside the view and then pass the correctly formatted data to the template.

This is good practice because soon enough you will want to perform more difficult transformations with the data which will be very hard if not impossible inside the django template. That is also why this kind of logic belongs inside the view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).